# Admin page to create new posts

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I created a login and an admin page.

On the admin page I created two text fields, the first one is for title and the second is for the content. I also created a submit button.

I have a database with a table called: node.

In that table I created: id(1,2,3...), author_id (1=me), header (it'd be the title), text (it'd be the content) and date(when it was posted).

Now all I want is when I push the submit button, the author, header, text and date appear on the page as a new post. It's pretty much the same thing when I push the 'Post your question' button here.

[Here's the webpage](http://hearthstone.wow-panda.com/)

I've created 3 test news posts from sql, it's working, but it'd be much better if I could do it from an admin page. :)

I'd greatly appreciate if You could write it down nicely, I've never done this and I don't really know how to do this one.

Before anyone'd offer: I do NOT want to create joomla or drupal website.

Final working version: (Thanks to Bansi)

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
{
    include('sql.php');
    $username =$_COOKIE["user"];
    $user = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select * from user where
    name='$username'"));
        if (empty($_GET['action']))
        {
            //This is where you add to database
            if (!empty($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='submit'){
            //do any validation if required, like not empty header and not empty body etc here
            $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
            $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
            }
            //insert to the database
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO hearthstone.node 
            ( author_id , title , text , date ) 
            VALUES ( '1', '$title', '$text', NOW( ) );");
        }
            ?>
<div id="adminmenu">Logged in as <b>
<?php print $user[1];?></b>
<span style="margin: 15px;"><br></span>
<?php include('logout.php'); ?>
<span style="margin: 15px;"></span>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>Title:</p>
<p><input type="text" maxlength="255" name="title" id="title" size="60"></p>
<p>Body content:</p>
<p><textarea cols="60" rows="20" name="text" id="text"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
</div>

            <?php
    }
else
{
        include('login.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: can you post the code to your admin page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Details below the code.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {
    include ('sql.php');
    $username = $_COOKIE["user"];
    $user = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select * from user where
    name='$username'"));
    if (empty($_GET['action'])) {
        //This is where you add to database
        if (!empty($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit'){
            //do any validation if required, like not empty header and not empty body etc here
            $header = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['header']);
            $body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']);
            //insert to the database
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO node (author_id,header,text,`date`) VALUES (1,$header,$body,now());");
        }
?>
<div id="adminmenu">Logged in as <b>
<?php print $user[1]; ?></b>
<span style="margin: 15px;"><br></span>
<?php include ('logout.php'); ?>
<span style="margin: 15px;"></span>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>Title:</p>
<p><input type="text" maxlength="255" name="header" id="title" size="60"></p>
<p>Body content:</p>
<p><textarea cols="60" rows="20" name="body" id="content"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit button" id="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
</div>

            <?php
    }
} else {
    include ('login.php');
}
?>
```

***Important : don't use mysql functions as it is depreciated try to use mysqli or PDO***

The is the changed code. I have added comment in the code where you save to database. I have also added `<form>` element to the `HTML`. The code is not tested as my server no longer supports `mysql` functions. I have tried my best to use the db name and field names from your question. Also note I have not added any error checking.

Please let me know if you encounter any problems.

Comment: any error messages? if so what? does the above query work?

Comment: It's working now, thanks for the help, it was good what you posted, just needed to change a bit, updated first post to final version.